# Running Multiple KMeans with Parallelism at the Same Time

Tags: scikit-learn, parallel-processing, openmp

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/17276), `KMeans` in Scikit-Learn >= 0.23 has changed its implementation. Now we can set `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to specify the number of parallel jobs for a KMeans.

My system (AWS EC2 with AL2) shows 32 from `nproc`. Without setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, KMeans uses all cores. This froze my system and I was not able to ssh into the host. Therefore, now when I run a KMeans, I set `OMP_NUM_THREADS=30`. While running KMeans with this setting, I found (from `top`) that the process does not always use all 30 cpus because I see many times "%CPU" is less than 3000.

So if I have two KMeans programs to run, can I run them at the same time wihtout freezing my system?

Comment: You haven't told us what your system is (which OS, in particular).  I'd guess lInux, but maybe you're using the LInux emulation in Windows. *IF* you are on LInux, `nice` may be your friend, since it should make the KMeans process (and its threads) run at lower priority, which ought to allow other things to run with less interference.

Comment: Sorry for the missing info. I am using AWS EC2 with AL2 (which is based on CentOS). Can you elaborate on how `nice` is used in my case?

Comment: `nice` (https://linux.die.net/man/1/nice) lets you lower the scheduling priority of the threads inside the process which it started so that they can be displaced more easily by other threads which want to execute. That means that things (such as the ssh daemon) should still be able to run when they need to, as they will have higher priority. If you're using LLVM or Intel compilers also set `KMP_BLOCKTIME=0` to have the OpenMP threads sleep in the kernel as soon as they are waiting, rather than polling for a while.